# xdotool in a shell script doesn't work properly with an xbindkeys

Tags: bash, xdotool, xbindkeys

I'm fighting with this quite a long time. I have a very simple script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  if [ ! -z "$(/usr/bin/xinput --query-state 17 | grep -o 'button\[12\]=down')" ]; then
    /usr/bin/xdotool click --delay 18 1
  else
    break
  fi
done
```

And I want to run it when I'm holding the mouse button 12, so the `.xbindkeysrc` file looks like this:

```
"bash ~/Scripts/test2.sh"
    b:12
```

And it works - `xbindkeys -v` shows the button 1 is spamming like crazy in terminal but clicks are not registered in the OS. I'm running Debian 12 with xfce so obviously I'm under X11. But, when I spam the button 12 it sometimes registers a few button 1 clicks. Also I tried to do some timing tricks and other things proposed in stackoverflow but with no luck.

Also when my config looks like this:

```
"xdotool click 1"
    b:12
```

It does the same, clicks are detected but click 1 commands are not registered by OS.

When I execute the script in terminal when I'm holding button 12 it works as intended and even quits when I release it so script is working fine. Anybody knows why `xdotool` running from `xbindkeys` is not working?

Comment: There is a chance I found the issue:
`"xdotool click 1"    b:12 + release`
Works just fine. That means `xbindkeys` does something to the held mouse button 12 which prevents button 1 to click properly. I have no other ideas. I can always change break in the script into waiting time and run the script as daemon but to make it responsive I would need to set a short sleep time which will make that daemon a way too CPU expensive...